# What is the reason why I am not able to able to use Maltego unless I disable port 135 (RPC) inbound on my Windows computer?

Tags: authentication, reconnaissance, distributed-computing

I originally attempted to use Maltego before making any configuration changes to my firewall; however, I was being blocked because I had port 135 disabled which is what Windows uses for RPC. After disabling the inbound rule, I was able to connect. Since I was using it for the Twitter OAuth service, shouldn't I only have to insure the OUTBOUND rule was not blocking port 135 opposed to the inbound for RPC?

According to Twitter Documentation it uses, OAuth to provide authorized access to it's API

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/oauth

I am not sure why it's being blocked with RPC as I am only using it from my knowledge as an outbound connection and I am using it to use the Twitter OAuth service through maltego.